# I don't find the error in my app. Only on a handful devices

Tags: java, android, fatal-error

I can't find, what's my mistake. The Errors appears only on a handful devices. I'm new in Java and I cant read the Error-Log so good:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: myapp.myapp, PID: 11585
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{myapp.myapp/myapp.myapp.Start}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2050: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2205)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:142)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2050: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:319)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1973)
    at myapp.myapp.Start.onCreate(Start.java:220)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:422)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2150)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:129)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:119)
```

I see, this a fatal error. And the App is closing from Android device. The Error occurs on a handful devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`.  It shows it at the last `Caused by` line.  Memory can be temporamental, since different devices have different amounts of memory, and it also depends on lots of other factors, like what other apps are running, size of screen etc...

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, you get an OutOfMemoryException. See the last bulk of the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:422)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2150)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:129)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:119)
```

It appears to be connected to an image, as it crashes when it tries to decode from a resource stream. This is because it cannot allocate enough memory for the image.

So I have three solutions:

- Make the image smaller (resize) --- Your app doesn't need as much memory to create the image
- Use a library like Picasso --- saw this solution elsewhere when it was directly linked to images. Picasso can help oyu load larger pictures into your app
- declare `android:largeHeap="true"` in the application tag in your manifest. --- Your app requests more memory, and this scales (up and down AFAIK) to suit whatever memory needs your app has

AFAIK, your app gets a given amount of memory when not requesting large heap. This amount varies from device to device, based on ROM and hardware.

The devices you get the crash on, probably have less memory. If you don't crash on an S8 edge, doesn't mean you will not crash on an S2. The resources available on the devices change, which is the reason you get the OOME on **some** devices and not **all**. I'm not sure what devices are on your crash list, but they may be the low-end budget devices with limited resources.

Answer (score 0):

Log shows that initial cause of crash is `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`. Probably some devices don't have enough memory to decode image file in assets of app. Check your assets folder and try to reduce size of images it contains.

Answer (score 0):

You run out of memory while trying to load an image. It can happen when you are trying to load a high resolution image and device. Check line #2050 in your layout XML file.

A possible solution is that you provide lower resolution resources (images) for the devices that cannot handle such images.